# How to get all elements by class name inside Iframe PEGA

Tags: javascript, iframe, pega

I am trying to get an element by its className inside an iframe. as I use IE5 "getElementsByClassName" is not working. To get any element inside my document I used pega with the following: `pega.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName("BlaBlaName");`
However, this is not working for me when the element is inside an Iframe. I only gets elementById from the iframe using `IframeinnerDoc.getElementById("IdBlala")`
How can I get the elements by tag name inside the iframe using Pega in IE5?

Comment: You still use InternetExplorer 5? You've got my respect.

Comment: Yes, if the client asks for IE5 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
pega.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName("BlaBlaName", "*", IframeinnerDoc);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `contentWindow`: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp

something like this might work:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myframe");
var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
if (y.document)y = y.document;
y.getElementsByClassName('foo')
```

Comment: actually, getElementsByClassName doesn't work on IE5.